# Ввод данных словаря с клавиатуры

Tags: python, словари

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как задать словарь с клавиатуры (через `input`)?

К примеру, в моем словаре должны храниться даты и события. Могу ли я использовать этот код? То есть я ввожу год и соответствующее событие в истории.

Comment: вы хотя бы написали что именно в словаре должно храниться

Answer (score 2):

например так:

```
data = dict()

while True:
    key = input('введите ключ: ')
    value = input('введите значение: ')

    data[key] = value
```

только какой-нибудь механизм выхода из цикла прикрутить стоит

Comment: Подскажите, как мне остановить этот цикл? То есть я ввёл достаточное количество ключей и значений и хочу получить заполненный словарь.

Comment: @StopTalking, например можете проверять что в качестве ключа ввели `stop` и делать `if key == 'stop': break` - логику уже вам выбирать то, универсальных средств нет

Comment: Спасибо я понял и немного изменил. Я написал код, но не получается выбрать те даты, которые входят в промежуток 19 века, можете посмотреть, как лучше поменять?
data = dict()

while True:
    key = (input('введите дату: '))
    value = input('введите событие: ')

    data[key] = value
    if input('Продолжать? /Нет ') == 'Нет' : 
    # при нажатии "enter" заполнение словаря
    # продолжится, при вводе "Нет" цикл прервется
        break

if 1799<(key[0])<1901:
  print(f'{key} - {data[key]}')

Answer (score 2):

```
dictionary = {}
length = int(input("Введите длину словаря:"))
for element in range(0,length):
  dictionary[input()] = input()
```

я плохо знаю питон, если ошиблась, простите *^_^*

Comment: интересное поведение у ```dictionary[input()] = input()```: принимает значение, потом - ключ...

Comment: @Jack_oS Вполне логичное. Чтобы что-то добавить, надо это что-то сначала получить.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов, а, понятно)